# Different querystring urlencoding based on codepage. ASP classic

Tags: utf-8, asp-classic, character-encoding, url-encoding

We are currently converting our webapp to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1. And everything works great but requesting get/post variables from other sites (Signup forms).

Some of this sites that post to our site have ISO-8859-1 encoding and som have UTF-8.

The problem is that special characters gets URLencoded differently depending on the site charset.

For example:
ø = %F8 in ISO-8859-1
ø = %C3%B8 in UTF-8

I cant get %F8 right when i have UTF-8 charset. I only get a Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD).

Any tips on how to fix this would be much appreciated:)

Torbjørn

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the encoding explicitly using `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`.

If you don't want to do that, the browser has to guess the encoding you want. For that it usually takes the encoding of the page in which the form is. So if you serve the HTML files as `UTF-8` your forms will be sent back as `UTF-8`, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Ok, so its not possible to convert the encoding on our server? There are alot of forms posting in to us, and i dont have access to them.

Comment: Not if you are not the one serving the form in the first place. Which it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you did a preanalysis of the inputs before converting them. Essentially, scan for the iso-8859-1 codes for Æ, Ø and Å (upper and lower case). If you find any, do a search/replace for the entire request, where you swap the iso-char codes to the UTF-8 charcodes.

Comment: Hmm, you might want to check up if any of the ISO-charcodes map to something plausably relevant in UTF-8.

Comment: Are there any classes that you know of that would be able to do this type of work or would I need to collect each of the individual characters I am having issues with?

Comment: I don't know of any specific classes that will do this for you. Since you are essentially overwriting whatever charactercode that was in the UTF-8 specification with the special character you needed.